# asp.net mvc ViewState implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I working on a web project where I first get data from the database and bind to the Html control. If there is a validation error I will send the same view back for rendering with the displayed validation errors. When the page comes up, there is an exception. I stepped through the code and found that the model was passed will null collection. Basically any property that was not binded to a textbox was changed to null. I was told not to use session or viewdata to keep temp storage. So I call a method SaveViewState where it save all the property value of the ViewModel property to a static variable like so

```
private static MyViewModel _viewModel;

private MyViewModel SaveViewModel(MyViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (_viewModel == null)
            {
                _viewModel = new MyViewModel ();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.MyName))
                _viewModel.MyName= viewModel.MyName;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.Number))
                _viewModel.Number= viewModel.Number;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.Address))
                _viewModel.Address= viewModel.Address;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.State))
                _viewModel.State= viewModel.State;
            }
```

It works but I think it is very inefficient and there must be a better way to implement ViewState in MVC with Session or ViewData or HiddenFields? By the way, I was told not to use those three.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Show how you are using a collection. If you post to an action that has the model as a parameter it should get filled.

Comment: One of the many reasons why MVC was developed was to get rid of `ViewState`. Your implementation will not work because its not thread safe (and it will all fail if more than 1 user is editing an instance of `MyViewModel`). If you do not create controls to post back all the data and need to return the view, then call the repository again to get the original object and populate the view model again with the missing values.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this solution is worse than using a session or hidden fields. In your action you should return the corresponding view with the same model that was posted. The ActionResult should be something like this:

```
public ActionResult SomePost(SomeModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid())
    {
         //error in validation
         return View(model);
    }

     //post save redirect and stuff
     return ... redirect? 
}
```

The `ModelState.IsValid()` will test according to the DataAnnotations. Standard attributes like `[Required]`, `[MaxLength]` etc. are available.

In this configuration, the use of a `SaveViewModel` function is not required. If your collection is `null` after post: re-query it, post it or fetch it from a ViewData like object.

There are good reasons not to use those three you mentioned, but if you know that reason you might want to consider it:

1) Use of session: will make scalability difficult because every request in a session must hit that specific server.

2) Hidden fields: Not really a problem IFF you realize the hidden field can be manipulated in a browser. So don't store ID's there

3) ViewData: basically breaks the MVC pattern; you can use it to store data but that's what a model is for. It totally legitimate to use ViewData from a filter. To provide some general functionality for example.